# Error: loading ... \sapjvm_8_jre\bin\server\jvm.dll when starting xs client of HANA Express 2.0

Tags: hana-xs

Trying to starting XS Client of SAP HANA Express Edition 2.0 SPS01 in the command prompt on Windows 10 machine did results in following error message:

```
...\xsclient\bin>xs
Error: loading ......\sapjvm_8_jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

As this was a blank new windows 10 (64bit) machine with not much installed, the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)** is missed. This can be download and installed directly from  Microsoft: [C++ Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=14632)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but a different solution. My version was 119. Download+install an older version. Version 85 worked for me for example. If you are on HANA 2.0, you can download it on service.sap.com ->Download Software and search for 'XS Runtime 1'.